# Finding $(a,b)$ in some given subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with a specific gcd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given the subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\supset S=\{(9(k+3),4k), k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ I’m trying to find $(x,y)\in S$ such that $\mathrm{gcd(x,y)}=18$. The set $S$ arises as the set of solutions to the equation $4x-9y=108,\; x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$. The equation isn’t particularly hard to solve, but I can’t quite figure out how to go about finding the couples $(x,y)$ with gcd 18.

Playing around a little I found that since I want $18$ to be the gcd of $9(k+3)$ and $4k$, 18 has to divide both, which implies $k$ is an odd number and $2k=9q$ with $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ but this still allows for the possibility of $\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)>18$, that is, those are necessary conditions but certainly not sufficient ones. And I’m not entirely sure where to go from there. This feels like it’s very easy and I’m just not seeing something obvious. Anyway, if anyone has a suggestion, a hint or something, I’d appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x=18a$ and $y=18b$ where $a,b$ are coprime, so we have $$4a-9b = 6$$ Clearly $2\mid 9b$ so $2\mid b$ and thus $b=2d$. Similary we see that $3\mid a$ so $a=3c$. Now we have $c-3d=1$ and thus $c= 3d+1$ where $d$ is arbitrary. Now we get $$x= 54(3d+1)$$ and $$y= 36d$$

Comment: After reading the first sentence in your answer I tried filling in the rest and ended up with something similar. Once done, I tried a few values for d, and it seems to not work, though I cannot quite see why. Indeed take $d=1,7$, and one gets $\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)=36$. If one take $d=9$, tou find $\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)=108.$ Again, I don’t know where something went wrong but I think something is slightly wrong somewhere.